# How to export the result from ec2 instance view in an excel file

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-ec2

I am using `JAVA SDK` for `AWS`. I can fetch the detail of the ec2 instances in a particular region in ec2 instance view. But how to import the result in an excel sheet.

Kindly help

Comment: pull the results in a hash, then convert the hash into CSV and then import that CSV in Excel. What have you tried so far and what difficulty are you facing while doing so ?

Comment: Actually i dont know how to write that result into a excel sheet. I have nt tried anything yet. I dont know how to do that

Comment: please help if you can, i think so sdk has been upgradated

Answer (score 0):

If the difficulty is in writing to excel, you can use [Apache POI library](http://poi.apache.org/) which again is in Java. It provides convenient APIs to write to Excel.

Examples are [here](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html):